# Spring AOP Aspect Annotation Logging

Tags: spring, logging, jakarta-ee, aop

we are using Spring AOP for logging the application code.but i am not able to log the controller servlet or any domain object
we are using a factory class and we are able to log the method of classes instantiated from this factory class

i have tried using component tag on the domain object or servlet,but still i am not able to solve the problem

can anyone provide solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to your spring servlet config file.

Answer (score 2):

The Compnent Annotation will not work, because the Instance is not Spring Manged if it is created by a normal `new` statement.

You could try to use the @Configurable annotation. But in my personal opinion, using AspectJ instead of Spring AOP would be the better solution, and AspectJ works on every object, not only on Spring Manged once..

Comment: thanks @Ralph..can anyone provide me pointer toward using AspectJ with spring application   we are already using aspect using aspectJ annotations and we have <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> in the spring config

Comment: @Vish: AspectJ works with Spring, in the same away how it works without Spring. But you should tell Spring that is uses AspectJ instead of Spring AOP: <task:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" executor="asyncExecutor"/>, <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />, ... --- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj -- Attention: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> is only about the style, not about the concreate AOP Implementation

Comment: @Vish: so what you need is an aspectJ compiler. If you use maven, then it is easy. I did not find any good example at the moment. But I think the best way to understand how it works, would be doing a small Spring Roo sample, and then examine the pom.xml and applicationContext.xml

Comment: thanks @Ralph for your suggestion..dont we have any way where we can use Spring AOP since we have done lot of work using Spring AOP..